# Is is bad practice to ID each (used) element in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am wondering what the best practice would be to manipulate certain elements in an html page using jquery.  As it stands now, I have a panel, with an embedded form which includes an input box, checkbox, submit/reset/test buttons.  Right now I have each of these elements assigned an id so I can take the appropriate actions as each element is changed/selected.  However, I feel as if my code is becoming quite messy and unreadable by assigning and managing each element by id.  I know that it is efficient for the browsers to select by id, but is it better to simply give the panel/form an ID, and then call different selectors inside of the panel/form?  Are there any suggestions for selecting some of the elements I have assigned IDs below? (The ones I am modifying..etc).  Thanks!

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="sample_panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Heading
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="form1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4>Subheading</h4>
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="input_addon">some_text</span>
                                <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" >some_text
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn id="reset_btn">Reset</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="test_btn">Test</button>
                        <i id="some_image"></i>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer" id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because it asks about best practices.

Comment: it's probably better long-term to use IDs on containers and classes/attribs on individual items, unless they are app-wide.

Comment: generally easier with repeating templates within the html to use classes and search within the parent class

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, thanks for the tip.. still new to posting so I apologize for posting in the "wrong" place.

Comment: `id`s create javascript variables on the global scope and that *might* lead to bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that IDs are unique identifiers, and for that reason should have more specific names. I would use them only when they are actually necessary, and when a class wouldn't be a better way to identify them.

Pile on the classes, but use IDs a bit more sparingly. I struggled with this as well when writing my first MVC app. Good luck!

Don't forget there is a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site on StackOverflow as well.

Answer (score 2):

I give id's to major elements in the page that contain subsets of the page, and also important and unique elements that I would want direct access to.  I don't give an id to each and every list item, link or div because it clutters the code and it's a potential maintenance nightmare.  You won't select most elements of the page, and you'll often access multiple elements at the same time - classes are vastly more useful for this.

So while you are correct that accessing elements by id is very quick and efficient, the selector system is powerful and useful because you can select elements in a variety of ways.  Take advantage of those other selection methods too, you'll get a lot more done with jQuery.

Comment: That is correct. I'm not entirely sure, but it seems that the more IDs you use the more work you are putting on the selector when you look for one. It might not be enough to matter though.

Comment: I don't think the number of ids used in a document affects selection.

Comment: I just assumed that having to search a list of 100 IDs on a loaded page would be slower than having to search a list of 15.

Comment: I think the id is like an index - knowing it gives you direct access.  There's no search involved.

Comment: My knowledge of the inner workings of jQuery selectors definitely isn't deep enough to challenge you on that :) Thanks for the input.